# How do I compare two regression coefficients when I group off the DV?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, modeling

I'm trying to see whether good players in chess (those with more than a 1250 Elo) are helped more by puzzles than bad players (those with less than a 750 Elo). Usually, the way I would do this is with an interaction term. However, in this case my DV (Elo, which is a measure of skill) is the thing I want to interact with the independent variables.

Below I have two models. One of them is with data for players with less than a 750 Elo and one is for players with more than a 1250 Elo. How do I tell whether the coefficient on something such as LifetimeLessons is different between the two models?

```
badplayermodel <- plm(PlayerELO600 ~ LifetimeLessons + LifetimePuzzles + 
                LifetimeAnalyzed600 + LifetimePlayed600 + Username, data = badplayerdf,
              index = c("Username","Date"), model = "within")

goodplayermodel <- plm(PlayerELO600 ~ LifetimeLessons + LifetimePuzzles + 
                         LifetimeAnalyzed600 + LifetimePlayed600 + Username, data = goodplayerdf,
                       index = c("Username","Date"), model = "within")
```

Comment: Couple thoughts before this gets migrated: 750 is an arbitrary cutoff for what could presumably be a continuous effect - putting ELO as a continuous variable (maybe fitted with a smoother in a GAM) in a single model might be better than picking 750 as a cutpoint between 2 models. And you say your goal is to measure who is "helped more"--so "helped" needs to be your response variable, not ELO - maybe a net change in ELO over a time period. But this is all very tricky--it's a lot easier to go from 600 to 700 than from 2200 to 2300.

Comment: Could you describe better your data?